# Why on scroll event not working on dynamic added div

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, jquery-events

I try many methods like

```
   $('.div').on('scroll',function(){}) // not working
   $(document).on('scroll' ,'.div' , function(){}) // not working 
   $('.div').scroll(function(){}); // not working
```

Now how can Apply scroll to dynamically added div?

Comment: What's your `HTML`? Your selector is used as `$('.div')` which will select any element with **Class** `div`, are you sure there's any element with those class? Or are you trying to select the **Tag** `div`, if so you need to remove the `.` in the selector so it become `$('div')` which will select any element with **Tag** `div`